# Clustered scans with urg_node and Hokuyo UST-10LX

Tags: ros, urg-node, frequency, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with the `urg_node` package and the Hokuyo UST-10LX lidar. And I've noticed that although the frequency of the `/scan` topic is indeed 40 Hz (which is in line with the nominal 2,400rpm of the lidar), when I measure the time diffs between callback calls, this is what I see: ...

```
0.258792
0.0479169
0.000181913
0.049917
0.000186205
0.0502079
0.000151396
0.0496333
0.000199556
0.0493841
0.050199
0.043467
0.0440154
0.000242233
...
```

That is, the callback calls are separated by ~50 or ~2 ms (which effectively yields an average of 40 Hz), but they are not evenly distributed in time. Output from `tostopic hz /scan` is the following:

```
....
average rate: 40.042
    min: 0.000s max: 0.057s std dev: 0.02226s window: 326
...
```

and the fact that "std dev" is so high is due to the observed clustering of messages.

I've checked the parameters passed to the `urg_node`, and made sure that `skip` is set to 0, and that `cluster` is set to 1 (meaning that messages should **not**  beclustered). I've also compiled the node with `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --pkg urg_node` but to no avail.

I've also tried to limit the amount of information transmitted from the node, and set the `angle_min` and `angle_max` to [-0.5, 0.5] but that also had no effect.

What am I missing? What other cause can there be of the messages being sent in this manner?

Any help would be very appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303464/clustered-scans-with-urg_node-and-hokuyo-ust-10lx/) by [MTDzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/35839/mtdzi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you made sure to make the subscriber disable Nagle (ie: specify "tcpNoDelay()" as a transport hint)?

`rostopic` cannot do this afaik, so that is not a usable measurement tool.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MTDzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/35839/mtdzi/) on 2018-09-16**:
It worked! :D
Thank you VERY much!